# Like Facebook page on button action

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, facebook-like, facebook-page

I'm trying to implement page like functionality from application, I've added latest `Facebook SDK` and implemented all delegates and handlers to check for session and status for the user login to the app. Its working fine up to here (this is already done in the sample code). Anyways, I've found the following code from the Facebook developer site, to like a page, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
- (void) likeFacebookIndia
{
    NSMutableDictionary<FBGraphObject> *action = [FBGraphObject graphObject];
    action[@"object"] = @"http://www.facebook.com/FacebookIndia";
    //action[@"object"] = @"FacebookIndia";
    [FBRequestConnection startForPostWithGraphPath:@"me/og.likes"
                                       graphObject:action
                                 completionHandler:^ (FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                                     id result,
                                                     NSError *error)
     {
         // handle the result
         if(error)
         {
             NSLog(@"%@",error.localizedDescription);
         }
         else
         {
             NSLog(@"%@",result);
         }
     }];
}
```

Once successfully logged in, I used to call above function, and it ends up with the following error in `likeFacebookIndia` block,

> The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 5.)

Here, my questions are,

1. I am not sure whether this is the correct way for liking a page?
2. If its correct, then what I am really missing to pass?
3. Is there any other way?

I already visited pages for `FacebookLikeView` and `FBLikeButton` also many question already aksed here, but not a single seems to work with latest `Facebook SDK` update.
I was able to like a page with `FacebookLikeView` but there's many problems with that,

1. A `UIKeyBoard` is showing up after like a page
2. Takes good time in loading Facebook page if login required and
3. After second like to the same page, like view goes out somewhere!

**Update**
I tested same thing on Graph API Explorer, and it comes with the following result,

[image: Graph API Explorer]

`{
 "error": {
    "message": "(#100) Like actions are not yet supported against objects of this type.", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 100
 }
}`

**Update 2**

I do hacked into `FacebookLikeView` classes and solved above problems I written, though it should work now? NO it's not working, as it is using `FBConnect` which is now outdated and also, I've latest `Facebook SDK` for other stuff which working nicely! *It would be good if someone will make new project with latest SDK for FacebookLikeView.* [I'm already working!]

This is how I'm doing,

```
//Calling this function in `viewDidLoad`

- (void) addLikeView
{
    facebookLikeView.delegate = self;
    facebookLikeView.href = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.facebook.com/FacebookIndia"];
    facebookLikeView.layout = @"button_count";
    facebookLikeView.showFaces = NO;
    facebookLikeView.alpha = 0;
    [facebookLikeView load];
}

#pragma mark - Facebook Delegate
-(void)sessionDoneForPageShare:(FBSession *)session state:(FBSessionState)state error:(NSError *)error
{        
    if(error)
    {
        NSLog(@"error : %@",error);
    }
    else
    {
        [facebookLikeView load]; //In logged in or logged out, we've to call this
    }
}

- (void)facebookViewControllerCancelWasPressed:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"Login was cancelled by user");
}

- (void)facebookViewControllerDoneWasPressed:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"User tapped done button on login view");
}

- (void) checkFBloggedInStatus
{
    if (!FBSession.activeSession.isOpen)
    {
        NSArray *permissions = [NSArray array];
        [FBSession openActiveSessionWithPublishPermissions:permissions defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceOnlyMe allowLoginUI:YES completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState status, NSError *error){
            [self sessionDoneForPageShare:session state:status error:error];}
         ];
    }
}

#pragma mark FacebookLikeViewDelegate methods
- (void)facebookLikeViewRequiresLogin:(FacebookLikeView *)aFacebookLikeView {
    [self checkFBloggedInStatus];
}

- (void)facebookLikeViewDidRender:(FacebookLikeView *)aFacebookLikeView {
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDelay:0.5];
    facebookLikeView.alpha = 1;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

- (void)facebookLikeViewDidLike:(FacebookLikeView *)aFacebookLikeView {
    NSLog(@"liked");
}

- (void)facebookLikeViewDidUnlike:(FacebookLikeView *)aFacebookLikeView {
    NSLog(@"unliked");
}

- (void)facebookLikeView:(FacebookLikeView *)aFacebookLikeView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"FacebookLikeView error: %@",error);
}
```

With this, I can see the like button, able to login into the browser, but then nothing will happen! It will just show Like button every time!

This was working good with old SDK `FBConnect`, the problem is with latest `Facebook SDK`,
you can find the `FacebookLikeView` [**here**](https://github.com/brow/FacebookLikeView),

What I'm missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Big Update !

If you're seeing this that means, now you don't need to patch (or hack) anything to support like (a page on Facebook or any Open Graph object) in your application. With latest release for Facebook iOS SDK (FacebookSDK.framework) they're supporting like button, however (while I'm writing this update) its in `beta`, but we've something that we're wished from a long time, *thank you Facebook*.

Here's the direct link for the change log and like button and yes documentation too.

- [Change Log](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/change-log-3.x/) (latest v3.19).
- [Like Button Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/like-button)
- [Facebook iOS Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios)

**Solution:** [RECOMMENDED]

> The Like button can be used to like a Facebook Page or any Open Graph
>   object and can be referenced by URL or ID. Here's what the code looks
>   like:

```
FBLikeControl *like = [[FBLikeControl alloc] init];
like.objectID = @"http://shareitexampleapp.parseapp.com/photo1/";
[self addSubview:like];
```

[image]

(Source : [Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/like-button)).

---

**Old school way** [NOT RECOMMENDED]

Finally, I'm able to solve my problem, I'm putting solution steps so it will really helpful to someone who's looking for this kind of stuff,

Some things you may need to know (from my question)

- I'm using FBConnect and Facebook SDK at the same time in my app.
- Both are working fine, FBConnect is only for `FacebookLikeView` -- You need to replace FBRequest class with some other name into FBConnect so it will not conflict with the latest SDK.
- Still need for some easy and quick solution as *this is not the perfect solution.*

So here we go,

**How do you get to know whether this particular page is liked by the user or not ?**

You need to use the Graph API with and check the User's likes. Here is an example.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{USER_ID}/likes/{PAGE_ID}
```

If the user likes the page in question, it will return JSON looking like this if the user likes the page.

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "SomeCafe", 
      "category": "Restaurant/cafe", 
      "id": "someIdWillCome", 
      "created_time": "2013-05-07T12:32:00+0000"
    }
  ], 
  "paging": {
    "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/me/likes/someIdWillCome?format=json&limit=5000&offset=5000&__after_id=someIdWillCome"
  }
}
```

And like this if the user doesn't like the page:

```
{
  "data": [
  ]
}
```

Here's the documentation on User likes:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#likes

**Implementation**

1) Implement `FacebookLikeView` as given on its docs.

2) I need to implement one HTTP request to call above URL to check the current status for that page as I couldn't get it from `FacebookLikeView`. **Remember, you need to do GET request along with access_token.**

3) Check into the response (close to above example) and do the things as you need!

### That's it!

Here's the solutions for `FacebookLikeView` issues I faced

---

1) `FacebookLikeView` went away somewhere?

Its because a comment popover hides it! below is the solution

In `FacebookLikeView.m` class look for, `- (void)didObserveFacebookEvent:(NSString *)fbEvent`

 And add these lines *in the end*,

```
if([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 5.0f)
{
    //NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(5_0);
    [[_webView scrollView] setContentOffset: CGPointMake (0, 0)];
}
```

2) FacebookLikeView shows UIKeyboard!!

It's because of the comment text box focus after like a page, below is solution for that.

```
- (void) keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    //force hide UIKeyBoard
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
}
```

Added notification into `viewDidLoad` into class where you implementing

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWasShown:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
```

> This will resign all keyboard visible from that particular view, in my case I'd no `UITextField` where I need the Facebook Like Button, so if your case is difference then make sure with this point.

3) The *slow loading* issue is depends on many things Facebook server, Internet connection or something else, so I added a loading indicator into it -- *It takes some time but working as I want!.*

---

> This will allow me like / unlike a Facebook page also I am able to know the current status of that particular user so I can decide what to do!

At last, thanks everyone who checked this issue and respond me! Appreciated! :)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for telling you bad news but You can't like a Page on behalf of a user. You can like posts, comments, and photos on behalf of a user but not pages (the likeview you mentioned is doing the same). If you try to do the latter you will receive an error

> "message": "(#3) Application does not have the capability to make
>   this API call."

But the good news is you can do it by using an iFrame which will load in a UIWebView. For now this is the only solution for integrating **PAGE** like button in native application. For further reading you can look through this resource: http://www.raywenderlich.com/1626/how-to-post-to-a-users-wall-upload-photos-and-add-a-like-button-from-your-iphone-app
There you can find a section

> Adding a Like Button to your Facebook Fan Page

Hope this will help you.

Comment: He has already implemented that piece and information shared by you is nothing new and known to many who works with iOS + Facebook. One will have to switch back to WebView logins in order to keep the Login/session sync with the user who is logged in. And keeping session etc in cookies will only help someone to like a page in iFrame (in Webview),but if a user is not using old SDK (which is outdated) will have to ask user to login to Safari or in a webview,which would mean two logins of the same user: one from Native app and one for Webview,if you want to play around with Pages Likes via iFrame.

Comment: If it is known to many dvelopers in that case why is this discussion open. If it is obviouse than why this guy posted this question?

Comment: Yes, If I started bounty on my question that means I'd tried the level best in getting this working, anyways thanks for your answer. The question is posted because to get perfect solution (I'm having feel that, "a Facebook developer will check it and will post an answer!"), as its highly concerned to huge developers community. Lets wait and watch!

Comment: Almost after 1.5 years, they heard @YervandKhalapyan ! They've added like button. xoxo :D ;)